# ACF Front Forms and Multsite

Tags: wordpress, forms, advanced-custom-fields

I have a 2x blog WordPress Multisite that contains a front end ACF form for adding dates.
I can then update these dates whenever required from the front end.

I want to load the front end form on the second blog so that I can also update the dates there.

I can load the form but the values aren't saved; whereas they are only the main blog site.

How do I get around this?

```
<?php 

          $options = array(
              'id'     => 'update_dates_form',
              'fields' => array(
                  'field_591c745961034',
                  'field_591c74a861037',
                  'field_591c748361035',
                  'field_591c749a61036',
              ),
              'submit_value'    => __('Save', 'augwp'),
              'updated_message' => __('Successfully Updated', 'augwp'),

          );

          acf_form( $options );
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, yiu have to switch to blog where data are stored, extract them then return to the current blog:

```
switch_to_blog(1);  // use blog number here, main blog is always 1
// extract data
restore_current_blog();
```

Comment: I've tried that and it loads the front end form but the fields are empty, even though they are filled out on the main blog (1).